# Splitting String with exception?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, split, string-length

I have string like this

```
string text = "224|3|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|2|You go back to meet the person from the Future.|1|You will be moved.|82|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|81|0|0|0|";
```

How can i split "|" this pipe character with exception so the result will be 3 section like this?

```
22430000000000002
You go back to meet the person from the Future.|1|You will be moved.
820000000000000081000
```

I have tried :

```
string[] line = text.Split('|');
Console.Write(line[0]); //until line[15] For print section #1 

Console.Write(line[line.length-2]); //until line[line.length-20] For print section #3
```

The text is dynamic , so maybe on section #2 it will be

```
You go back to meet the person from the Future.|1|You will be moved.|2|Hello
```

So when the index reach [16] the text is not being split until line.length-20
Is this possible ?
Thank you !!

Comment: Would it not be possible to select a different separator for the inner text? Is the number of the numberic separators (to the left and to the right of the text) fix?

Comment: Or possibly use JSON format to store the data, with the `|` being used as a field placeholder within the text messages.

Comment: A more structured format is the way to go.

Comment: Agree with Martin. If you can choose a different selector for the inner text, such as 224&3&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&0&2|You go back to meet the person from the Future.!1!You will be moved.|82&0&0&0&0&0&... Then splitting would be a snap.

Comment: It's not possible to reliably use `Split` if the data itself may contain the separator that `Split` is called with - `Split` has no way of knowing which separator is important for splitting and which isn't. You either need to parse these strings (possibly use regex) or use a different separator inside the messages.

Comment: The number to left and to right of the text is fix , [15] index (left side of the text) and then [19] index (right side of the text) , i have the text similar like this about 17k line ++ ,

Comment: @user3409182 If the number of fields before and after the text is fixed, just use a regex to grab the fields. It'll be a somewhat longish regex but simple.

Comment: @Frecklefoot yeah but i have the line of text like this about 17k++ line , when i replace it in notepad++ / notepad , how much spending time to do this ? hahaha :(

Comment: @xxbbcc i dont understand about regex , but if i succeeded split before and after the text , the text on the middle is already split right? , how can i grab it again ?

Comment: @user3409182 Don't use `Split` at all for this - it _won't work reliably_ if you have the separator also as data. Use a regex that looks for 15 `|`-separated numeric fields, a random text field and so many other fields at the end. Or, alternatively, use a better storage format, like JSON (if you can convert all your data lines to a new format). Using JSON (or even a different separator) would make your work a lot simpler.

Comment: @xxbbcc are regex is the last solution ? can i use other method? like counting 15 `|` -> get the text with | for (section #1) then assign it to some variable , find (section #1) on original text , replace it , do that again for (section #3) , finally get the middle text ?

Comment: @user3409182 Sure, you can if you don't mind writing / testing all that code for no practical gain.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A bit contrived, but working assuming you want to separate the inner letters from outer digits:

```
string text = "224|3|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|2|You go back the person from the Future.|1|You will be moved.|82|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|81|0|0|0|";

var first = String.Join("", text.TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '|'));

var third = String.Join("", text.Reverse().TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '|').Reverse());

var second = text.Replace(first, "").Replace(third, "");
```

Comment: This is a very contrived solution (although it does work). I'd most definitely recommend against this.

Comment: @xxbbcc this solution work for me , why you are not recommend this solution ? (i'm newbie for C#)

Comment: @w.b can you explain line by line of your code except the text variable ? this solution working for me but i just want to know the detail :)

Comment: @user3409182 - have a look at `Enumerable.TakeWhile` at msdn: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb534804(v=vs.100).aspx

Comment: @user3409182 It uses LINQ to separate the first part containing digits or `|` chars, then the same approach to separate the last part - it has to be reversed twice as this time it searches backwards, and subtracts these parts from the original text to get the middle part.

Comment: @w.b thank you! , your script don't work to this text : `507|292|1011|300|1016|3|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|272| |1|Yes, Thank you! Here, take it.|3189|1016|-3|1011|-300|2758|1|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|` the second var give me this output ` |1|Yes, Thank you! Here, take it.|3189|1016|-3|1011|-` why? because of minus ?

Comment: @user3409182 because there is a `-` between the digits in the last part, you can add it to the `TakeWhile` condition like `TakeWhile(c => Char.IsDigit(c) || c == '|' || c == '-')`.

Comment: @w.b thank you very much!! it solved my problem, I accepting this for the answer , thank you for your answer w.b :)

Comment: @user3409182 no problem, glad I could help